# How does gmapping detect loop closure?

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to know the way to detect loop closure in gmapping package.
I couldn't find loop closing method in gmapping papers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199781/how-does-gmapping-detect-loop-closure?/) by [infiniti](https://answers.ros.org/users/21167/infiniti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-12-18

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2014-12-18**:
Its through the ICP (iterative closest point) scan matching technique. Read [here].(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point)

**Comment by [infiniti](https://answers.ros.org/users/21167/infiniti/) on 2014-12-19**:
Thank you for your reply.
If loop closure is found, will all historical pose be recalculated?
I want to get recalculated pose data.
Is there a good method to do that?

**Comment by [Kislyy_homyak](https://answers.ros.org/users/89017/kislyy_homyak/) on 2021-11-21**:
Hey! did you end up with loop closures? I can't activate it. set resampleThreshold equal to 1, all the same the new map is superimposed on the old one

**Comment by [hunterlineage1](https://answers.ros.org/users/110678/hunterlineage1/) on 2023-04-15**:
@infiniti @AlexR @Kislyy_homyak
I am unable to get proper loop closure in gmapping slam, I set the resample Threshold equal to 0.8, were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[gmappinp Parameter](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping#Parameters)  `resampleThreshold` handles this.

> ~resampleThreshold (float, default:
> 0.5) The Neff based resampling threshold

---

`Neff` drops in case of loop closures.

gmapping does resampling based on  `Neff` threshold in case of loop closure.

[image: image description]

---

Check [rbpf slam tutorial](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Estachnis/pdf/rbpf-slam-tutorial-2007.pdf) . Pictures is from these slides.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Orl](https://answers.ros.org/users/38968/orl/) on 2022-07-07**:
Doesn't seem to work well. What value of Neff do you think is ok?

**Comment by [hunterlineage1](https://answers.ros.org/users/110678/hunterlineage1/) on 2023-04-13**:
I tried using a Neff value of 0.8 and it seemed to make things better in terms of updating the map. According to the slides:
"We only resample when Neff drops below a given threshold (N/2)" So setting resampleThreshold to 0.8 instead of 0.5 means resampling is done when fewer particles are needed to reach the sampling threshold.